# Unable to get operators to change color on settings file for vscode

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to override the color of the operators in vscode via the `settings.json` file. It's not quite working the way I want it to.

The `=` sign is the only one changing to the color `#EF596F`, but not `==`, `//`, `!=`, etc.

Below is my current `settings.json` configuration:

[image]

Comment: Did you check the scope of those others?  `TM Scopes....` in the command palette.

Comment: did you use a new unit? (kilOmeters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to successfully change the operators by altering the color of the keyword.operator in the themes .json file[image]